# Add FTP user with all directories access (like root) with Virtualmin / Webmin

Tags: ftp, webmin

It has been 2 hours that I' trying to allow a FTP user to have grant access to all directories.
I've add a FTP user with Webmin. I'm able to connect with a FTP client but when I'm trying to change directory to a virtual site (in /home/***), I have

```
    550 ****: No such file or directory
```

I just want this new user to have the same right as root user. (for ftp directories access).
Does someone can help me ?

Thanks you in advance !

Answer (score -1):

webmin has restrictions on creating ftp users with root permissions, there is a setting somewhere i think to disable this though, reply if you are still interested.

Comment: Hi, yes I'm still interested ! Do you remember where this option is ?